# I want to search box into Google play search box that effect

Tags: android

I want to search box into Google play search box that effect, but I try to never realize, how to customize the effect, who can help me solve this.!

Comment: and your own effort so far?

Comment: Well, yes, like the Google play search box that won't do, I'm Chinese, language is not good, the unclear description

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SearchView component in android ,refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - [Persistent Search Library](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch)